# How to extract the title of a youtube video using python

Tags: python

I want to extract the title,img thumb etc  of a youtube video ? how can i do this in python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lxml` parser and xpath expressions to fetch the content you require.
For, example to extract `title` of a youtube video-

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree
youtube = etree.HTML(urllib.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQEOBZLx-Z8").read()) //enter your youtube url here
video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title") //get xpath using firepath firefox addon
print ''.join(video_title)
```

'12 Days of Christmas -  Christmas Carol'

and now use similar xpath expressions to fetch whatever content you require.

Answer (score 11):

You definitely want to use the Youtube API, as C. Reed said.  This code will show you the title and author of a youtube video:

```
 import urllib
 import simplejson

 id = 'KQEOBZLx-Z8'
 url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%s?alt=json&v=2' % id

 json = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

 title = json['entry']['title']['$t']
 author = json['entry']['author'][0]['name']

 print "id:%s\nauthor:%s\ntitle:%s" % (id, author, title)
```

will print

```
id:KQEOBZLx-Z8
author:hooplakidz
title:12 Days of Christmas -  Christmas Carol
```

There is a lot you can with the Youtube API, for instance, if you want to just get the related videos and their authors you can specify in the URL: `fields=entry(id),entry(author)`

like: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/4y9kjrVejOI/related?fields=entry(id),entry(author)&alt=json&v=2&prettyprint=true

Comment: Unfortunately Google now has closed this kind of unauthenticated API access.

Comment: Yes, quite unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider the YouTube API for python: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python.html
you can easily retrieve titles, posting user, date of post, rating, comments, etc.

Comment: thanks to everyone for their answers it helps me lot .........

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python?csw=1#retrieving-a-specific-video-entry