# Getting title from youtube

Tags: python, youtube

So I used the example from this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775928/2232888

```
import urllib
import json as simplejson

id = 'KQEOBZLx-Z8'
url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%s?alt=json&v=2' % id

print urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

title = json['entry']['title']['$t']
author = json['entry']['author'][0]['name']

print "id:%s\nauthor:%s\ntitle:%s" % (id, author, title)
```

and it works fine for this example. 
however for this video I get ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
url = r'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFIwaHnYuO8&feature=youtu.be'

I'm suspecting it's becuase it's in hebrew but I haven't been able to debug it. Thanks.

Comment: There also is a python project that can retrieve a youtube title for you : [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl). I never used it as a python library though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the url Variable wrong this code will get the json for your video;

```
import urllib
import json as simplejson

id = 'YFIwaHnYuO8'
url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%s?alt=json&v=2' % id

print urllib.urlopen(url)
json = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))

title = json['entry']['title']['$t']
author = json['entry']['author'][0]['name']

print "id:%s\nauthor:%s\ntitle:%s" % (id, author, title)
```

## How does it work ?

The url you need was; http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/YFIwaHnYuO8?alt=json&v=2

So you enter "YFIwaHnYuO8" in the id Variable, you don't change the url Variable to a video link. You can get this id by examining the youtube video url "youtube.com/watch?v={your id }&feature=youtu.be".

Also it won't hurt to learn a little about string formatting, because that's how the url is build.

```
a = "We"
b = "join"
c = "%s %s" % (a, b)

c output = "We join"
```