# how to find correct youtube xpath for python

Tags: python, xml, video, xpath, youtube

I want to get information including video title, videoID, video post time, video viewers from videos on Youtube. But I don't know how to find the correct xpath. The following code is suggested by [How to extract the title of a youtube video using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738916/how-to-extract-the-title-of-a-youtube-video-using-python)

I have tried to use inspect of 'Chrome' and firebug of 'firefox', but all these didn't work for the code (the xpath found is : //*[@id="container"]/h1). The result is all empty list.

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree

youtube = 
etree.HTML(urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/watch?
v=Tqyu6E_k_cg").read()) 

video_title = youtube.xpath("//span[@id='eow-title']/@title")

print (''.join(video_title))
```

So how should I find the correct xpaths for videoID, viewers, postdate that can wor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
video title : //*[@class='watch-title']
view count : //*[(@class='watch-view-count')]
upload date: //*[(@class='watch-time-text')]
```

Video ID can be fetched from URL.

Comment: Thank you so much. Because I didn't learn anything about html or xml, so it's really hard fro me to find these things. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tqyu6E_k_cg")
youtube = html.fromstring(page.text)


video_title = youtube.xpath("//*[@class='watch-title']/text()")
video_count = youtube.xpath("//*[(@class='watch-view-count')]/text()")
video_date = youtube.xpath("//*[(@class='watch-time-text')]/text()")
```

After modification, this code works!!

Comment: If any suggestions, please post them without hesitation.