# fast web scraping on youtube in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, youtube

i have a list of youtube video links, about 200 links and i want to get for each link the title, the method i currently use is this

```
import youtube
for i in linklist :


        print((YouTube(i).title))
```

the problem is that it takes about a second for each title and it seems to me really too much, before I used this code which was MUCH faster but after about thirty links it returned the error: error 401 unauthorized

```
for i in linklist :

    params = {"format": "json", "url": i}
    url = i
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    url = url + query_string
    print(url)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        response_text = response.read()

    data = json.loads(response_text.decode())
    print(data['title'])
```

I got the first code from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrhevTF6xuQ
while the second from here :[How to extract the title of a youtube video using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738916/how-to-extract-the-title-of-a-youtube-video-using-python)

Comment: some modules may use normal web-scraping to get data - but Google (which is owner of YouTube) may detect scripts and block them (because scripts doesn't watch Ads and Google doesn't earn money). Usually faster method is to use API but sometimes it needs to register developer's account to get API keys to access data. Sometimes it may need also to pay for access to data.

Comment: Consider use pytube or another API - as mentioned in the previous comment.